# How can I have each plot in matplotlib's `subplots` use a different axes?

Tags: matplotlib, axes

So when I try to graph multiple subplots using `pyplot.subplots` I get something like:

[image: Four subplots]

How can I have:

1. Multiple independent axes for every subplot
2. Axes for every subplot
3. Overlay plots in every subplot axes *using* subplots. I tried to do `((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = subplots` and then do `ax1.plot` twice, but as a result, neither of the two showed.

Code for the picture:

```
import string
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WX')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip,chain


f,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex='col',sharey='row')

ax1.plot(range(10),2*np.arange(10))
ax2.plot(range(10),range(10))
ax3.plot(range(5),np.arange(5)*1000)
#pyplot.yscale('log')
#ax2.set_autoscaley_on(False)
#ax2.set_ylim([0,10])


plt.show()
```

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? What do you mean by "_multiple_ independent axes for _every_ subplot"? Also, with "Axes along every subplot" do you mean that you want to have _independent_ axes (i.e. not sharing x- or y-axis with other subplots) for every subplot, where each subplot has ticklabels? What do you mean by "overlaying plots in every subplot axes using subplots"? **Please be specific**, and make sure it's easily understandable what you want to achieve. If you have any images etc. of what you want it to look like, please refer to them.

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 7):

**Questions 1 & 2:**

To accomplish this, explicitly set the subplots options `sharex` and `sharey=False`.

replace this line in the code for the desired results.

```
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

Alternatively, those two options can be omitted altogether, as `False` is the default. (as noted by *rubenvb* below)

**Question 3:**

Here are two examples of adding secondary plots to two of the subplots:

(add this snippet before `plt.show()`)

```
# add an additional line to the lower left subplot
ax3.plot(range(5), -1*np.arange(5)*1000)

# add a bar chart to the upper right subplot
width = 0.75       # the width of the bars
x = np.arange(2, 10, 2)
y = [3, 7, 2, 9]

rects1 = ax2.bar(x, y, width, color='r')
```

[image: Subplots with independent axes, and "multiple" plots]

Comment: False is the default. The OP is setting them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't tell it to share axes:

```
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax1.plot(range(10),2*np.arange(10))
ax2.plot(range(10),range(10))
ax3.plot(range(5),np.arange(5)*1000)
```

[doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)

Comment: Is that something WX-backend dependent? With the axes only partially shared with `sharex='col',sharey='row'` it does work for me. See:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5599482
Or perhaps the code and the screenshot in the OP dont match.

Comment: :/ How can I prove the code and screenshot go together? It looks like that for me: http://i.imgur.com/p4Kftwa.png

Comment: Also how would I overlay plots _in_ shared axes?

Comment: what do you mean by overlay?  Show more than one plot in a given axes?

Comment: ex 4 plots that all share x,y axes, and THEN overlay a bar graph on top of one of them that uses the same/ different axes to the 'right' of the graph?